# Is it possible to pass a class to a Javascipt function?

Tags: javascript, css, function

I am currently passing the ID on buttons to a function.
I want to switch from using buttons to using the td in a jQuery table (as soon as I learn how to do so).
I want to change to using a class as I want to make each td in a row clickable.
Each td in a row will pass exactly the same variable to the function.

So each td in a row will perform exactly the same as the button.
Meaning I want to make the td clickable and to call the function.
All the td would have the same id (clear - in the example above) and I read it is bad practice to use the same id more than once and might present problems later in my jQuery code. I did read that it is ok to use a class multiple times, hence the attempt to make the change.

For example one button is set as below:

```
<input type="button" id="clear" style="width:110px;" onclick="return SetShift(this.id)" value="Clear" />
```

The SetShift function is:

```
function SetShift(id) {

    // Gets/passes the workday shift to/from the localStorage.
    const targetStateValue = localStorage.getItem('shiftstatus');

    if (targetStateValue === null) {
        localStorage.setItem('shiftstatus', id);
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem('shiftstatus', id);
    }
}
```

I tried to change the id to class, but I get the following errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token class

Uncaught ReferenceError: SetShift is not defined
at HTMLInputElement.onclick ((index):36)
```

Comment: `class` is a reserved keyword in js, meaning you can't use it for your variable names.

Comment: Why can't you pass only `this`, with that you can get entire properties of the tag.

Comment: @Khauri Thanks. I did suspect this as Notepad2 changes the color of the word class to brown and leaves it as black for id (now I know what the color brown means in Notepad2). I think I will continue to use id and think about an alternative if I run into any problems later in the jQuery code.

Comment: i'd recommend adding the `onclick` listener either programatically with `addEventListener` to the `<td>`, or better yet on a parent element and leverage [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) to handle these types of calls.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, `class` is a reserved name in JavaSript (see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes))

What you can do is this:

```js
function SetShift(evt) {
 console.log('className', evt.target.className);
}
```

```html
<button class="clear" onclick="SetShift(event)">
Click me
</button>
```

Note that if you have multiple classes, you'll need to use `classList.contains`

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to pass a class to a Javascipt function?

Yes, you can use [className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) property to do it:

```js
function setShift(className) {
  console.log(className);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="first" onclick="setShift(this.className)">First</td>
    <td class="second" onclick="setShift(this.className)">Second</td>
    <td class="third" onclick="setShift(this.className)">Third</td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

Comment: Thanks Kirill. This works really well with my buttons. Going to try and convert the buttons to the jquery table td now.